# Android: Specifying a literal '@'?

Tags: android, xml

Is there a way to set some attribute to the character '@' ?
i.e. explicitly *not* referencing any resource, just want the '@' sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out... just prefix it with \ i.e.:

```
<Button android:text="\@" />
```

It seems the character '?' requires escaping as well.